# Reduction formula doubt.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

If $$I_n = \int{(\frac{1}{a^2+x^2})^{n}}dx$$

Prove that:$$I_n = \frac{x}{2a^2(n-1)(a^2+x^2)^{(n-1)}}+\frac{2n-3}{2(n-1)a^2}I_{n-1}$$

I used Ibp but couldn't get such a relation. Please help me. Also, please do not use induction.

Comment: is $$I_n = \int\frac{1}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^n}dx$$?

Comment: @Chinny84 I didn't get u

Comment: The reason being is - you are creating recurrence relation based on powers in this case. But your first integral is not dependent on $n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
 By parts, setting $\,u= \dfrac1{(a^2+x^2)^{n-1}}$, $\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu v=\mathrm d\mkern1mu x$,  whence
$$\mathrm d\mkern1mu u=\frac{-2(n-1)x}{(a^2+x^2)^n}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x,\enspace v=x $$
One obtains then
$$I_{n-1}=\dfrac x{(a^2+x^2)^{n-1}}+2(n-1)\int\frac{x^2}{(a^2+x^2)^n}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x$$
Note that, writing $\,x^2=a^2+x^2 -a^2$, the integral is equal to  $\,I_{n-1}-a^2I_n$.

Comment: If $I_n(x)=\int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$ then $I_{n+1}(x)=\frac{x}{2n(1+x^2)^n}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_n(x)$?

Comment: @ThePoorJew: If  I have no error, yes it should be so.